# Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\tempahperalatan\page1.php on line 30 Error:

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hi im a beginner in php can anyone tell me what's the problem here? i cant seem to solve it. this is my php coding:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tempahperalatan";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $pemohon = $_POST['namaPemohon'];
    $trkhMula = $_POST['tmula'];
    $trkhAkhir = $_POST['takhir'];
    $n_program = $_POST['namaProgram'];
    $lokasi = $_POST['lokasi'];
    $n_anjuran = $_POST['namaAnjuran'];
    $catatan = $_POST['catatan'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO daftartempah (pemohon, trkhMula, trkhAkhir, n_program, lokasi, n_anjuran, catatan) VALUES ('$namaPemohon', '$tmula', '$takhir', '$namaprogram', '$lokasi', '$namaAnjuran', '$catatan')";

}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { //this is line 30
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

does it has anything to do with my xampp? thankyou in advance :)

Comment: The simple explanation is: at the popint where you call: `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` the $sql variable is empty.
There are two important points in your code where you could improve yourself a bit:
1. The first point is that you fill the `$sql` variable only if `$_POST['submit']` is isset, so if the post is empty, $sql is not filled but the mysqli_query-function can be called anyway.

2. The second point is that you should avoid using variables in a string. variables are evaluated in double quoted strings, but not in single quoted ones.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: P.S. Your stated problem has nothing to do with XAMPP and everything to do with logic. Your code is something trying to run a query you haven't defined (i.e. when it's not a postback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code block

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { //this is line 30
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

inside the

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

just below the $sql = [...]

otherwise the script will try to execute a non existent query if your form isn't submitted

Answer (score 0):

below $sql ,Take  one Variable

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
if($rows!=0)
{
  echo "Record inserted";
}
```